# process multiple key down in python?

Tags: python

i am very new in python, i have multiple options such as 1 to 99 and i want to select 23 as an windows after pressing f2 i press 2 and 3 and then press enter, number 23 is get selected. i want to do this in ubuntu 10.04. what will be procedure? i am writting some code

```
def keyDown(self,e):
    if e.keystring == "f2":                
        selectedNumber = 0
    elif e.keystring == "enter":
        print selectedNumber
        selectedNumber =0
    else:
        selectedNumber +=int(e.keystring)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: `keydown` looks like a callback taking an event parameter. Are you using some sort of library? You should list that here if you are.

Comment: this certainly would not work as selected Number is not saved between a call and another self.selectedNumber would be better probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the selected number as a string and when enter is pressed convert the number to an int. More input validation would be needed, but this should give you the idea.

```
def keyDown(self,e):
    if e.keystring == "f2":                
        selectedNumber = ""
    elif e.keystring == "enter":
        print int(selectedNumber) # If you are only printing you don't need int()
        selectedNumber = ""
    else:
        selectedNumber += e.keystring
```

Comment: ohh i was doing mistake, selectedNumber was showing undefined even i have define in class level but when i use self.selectedNumber instead selectedNumber its working. thank you all for reply

`def keyDown(self,e):
    if e.keystring == "f2":                
        self.selectedNumber = ""
    elif e.keystring == "enter":
        print int(self.selectedNumber)
        self.selectedNumber = ""
    else:
        self.selectedNumber += e.keystring`